# Eclipse Project Explorer Icons or Name

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In the Eclipse Project Explorer, I wish to add either a special icon or modify the name of a project to display whether a certain project parameter is set for a project. Is this possible, if yes how can I do it? I do not want to change the name of the project because that will mess up other items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can only be done by creating an Eclipse plugin. I believe following may fit the bill:

1. Label decorators ([Decorators extension point](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_decorators.html))
2. Project natures/nature images ([Nature images extension point](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_ide_projectNatureImages.html))

Comment: This worked great thank you. One last question. Can I add a tester to only enable the decorator when a certain condition is true?

Comment: @ScottJ I don't know. Are you using org.eclipse.ui.decorators extension point? The extension point description shows the enablement element, but I don't know if it simply disables the decorator globally or can be evaluated before running the decorator.

Comment: I can be used to add the decorator to a certain type of resource but I would like to add it to a certain subset of those resources. If I add: <enablement> <objectClass value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject"></enablement>, it will add it to all IProject items. What I would like to do is add a property tester that will allow me to check certain properties of the IProject. When I add the property tester, <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject.myTester" value="true"/>, I get a null pointer exception when I run my plugin. Is there a variable param I need to add before the tester?

Comment: @ScottJ What is the exception stack frame? Note that you may want to adapt object to IProject first so your plugin works with views other the Resource Explorer.

Comment: I solved this. You can add a class to the decorator extension that will determine when the decorator shows. Just create a class that extends ILightweightDecorator and add the checks in the decorate method.